# Converting ABC'D to De-Morgans

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

How would I go about doing this in steps

convert this expression to De-Morgans so that is uses NAND gates Only

[image]

Comment: DeMorgan's theorem is a method, not a destination.  You can't convert a circuit "to" it.

Comment: oops, I mean the expression ABC'D

Comment: You can't convert an expression "to" DeMorgan's theorem, either.  You probably mean "Implementing `ABC'D` using only NAND gates", and knowing DeMorgan's Theorem helps to do that.  But "using only NAND gates" is the destination.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: "Implement/Convert this circuit using/to use NAND gates only, using De-Morgans theorem." Which sounds a lot like homework. We aren't here to do your homework for you. Show your attempts so far.

Comment: Also, the easiest way doesn't even need DeMorgan's Theorem.  Just build each AND gate from two NANDs (wire the second one as an inverter).

Comment: You are correct this is homework but I do not know how to do it hence asking on here how to do it.

Comment: Hint: you can always build any Boolean expression from `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` functions. So break down the problem into, 1. how do you implement the `AND` function using only the specified `NAND` gates, and same for the `OR` and `NOT` functions, next 2. substitute your NAND-based `AND`/`OR`/`NOT` functions into the original expression, and then finally 3. simplify e.g. replace NOT(NOT(X)) with X. You can check your work by building a truth table; if the expressions are the same then the truth tables will match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *This seems like homework (or at least self-learning in the style of homework), so I'm deliberately providing you with the means to solve your problem, rather than the answer itself, although the answer shouldn't be too much of a stretch.*

---

So you have `ABC'D` using `NAND` logic only. A quick [truth-table review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table), taken straight from any respectable textbook on boolean logic:

```
A | B | A & B | A NAND B
--+---+-------+---------
0 | 0 |   0   |    1
0 | 1 |   0   |    1
1 | 0 |   0   |    1
1 | 1 |   1   |    0
```

That should already help you. Now you certainly don't need DeMorgan to tell you `A NAND B` is the same as `NOT(A & B)`. The power comes when you *combine* these truth table building blocks, and now you have a starting point.

Next, what is the truth table of the entire circuit (`ABC'D`)?

```
A | B | C | D | ABC'D = (A&B) & (NOT(C)&D)
--+---+---+---+---------------------------
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   0
0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |   0
0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |   0
0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |   0
0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Continue counting in binary...
```

Once you fill in all 2^4 = 16 states in that truth table, you should have an easy time figuring out how to use the `NAND` truth table to implement the circuit with `NAND` logic only. Truth tables are tremendously valuable for problems such as this, and, in fact, could help you *derive* many of DeMorgan's laws.

Yes, truth tables can be a little tedious, and like many tools, they aren't strictly *necessary,* but they're also extremely intuitive and reliable, so when you get stuck, that's a good time to start writing out 0s and 1s. For non-trivial problems, you'll have a tough time keeping the logic in your head.

## General approach

Generally, when given a complete diagram, you can follow these steps (of course you can skip a step here and there if you know the logic won't suffer):

1. Study the diagram down to the individual gate and input level
2. Write out the truth table for each input -> subgroup -> group -> ... -> entire circuit output, either working your way down from the overall circuit, or up from individual gates, or (quite commonly) a little bit of both!

   Now you have nicely broken-down truth tables, as well as logic expressions, for the useful partitions of your circuit.
3. Take your overall truth table / logic expressions and start to factor out parts that you can modify in the requested manner. (e.g., start identifying `AND(x,y)` gates you can turn into `NAND(NAND(x,y)`)
4. Now you can reverse the process in #2 with your updated logic.

This will work from small "toy" circuits all the way up to some fairly complicated logic, where more rigorous methods (and likely, software) will be the next progression in your studies.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZYrIk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Given that the NAND Gate CD has an Inverter to change the C current flow into an inverted C. This multiplies with the current flow D in the NAND Gate CD. This is multiplied with NAND AB to make an equation of \$ Y= AB \overline{C} D \$